# Why does IntelliJ propose RegExp.[Symbol.matchAll] instead of RegExp.matchAll?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

The code-completion in IntelliJ only proposes `RegExp.[Symbol.matchAll]`, but not `RegExp.matchAll`:
[image]

Typescript config settings:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
  },
```

What can be the reason for this?

### More info:

- `/x/[Symbol.matchAll]("axb")` works at runtime (NodeJs 14).
- `string.matchAll()` works, but `RegExp.matchAll()` doesn't:
  [image]
- Typescript version 4.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `Regex.prototype.matchAll` method.

There *is* a [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) method (which calls the method keyed to `Symbol.matchAll` under the hood), and there is a method on [`Regex.prototype[Symbol.matchAll]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@matchAll) that behaves similarly, which is why your IDE is autocompleting it that way for you. Not sure why they decided to have the convenience method for Strings but not Regexes.

Comment: Thanks. It's really strange, that Regex does not have `matchAll`..

Comment: @TmTron yeah, although given that it's the web the answer is almost certainly because a popular library in the past monkey patched the Regex prototype with a matchAll method incompatible with the standard one and they don't want to break existing sites.